# Inject meta tags per page

Tags: html, laravel-5, meta-tags, laravel-blade

So I run a Laravel 5.4 project and we have a system whereby each page would require separate META tags to correctly show when people tweet urls etc. So my question:

**How do I go about injecting the below code into my head tags?**

e.g. A new article might look like this:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@mysite">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="News Article - Donald Trumps Twitter Deleted!">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="imageurl">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Donald Trump lost access to his twitter for...">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="https://www.example.com">
<meta name="description" content="Donald Trump lost access to his twitter for..."/>
<meta name="keywords" content="News, Donald, Trump, Media, Reporting, Urgent, Breaking, Twitter"/>
```

.

Whereas something for say a forum post would look like this:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@mysite">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Forum - Welcome to the forum!">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="imageurl">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Hey there and welcome to our forum! For the chance to win $250 please...">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="https://www.example.com">
<meta name="description" content="Hey there and welcome to our forum! For the chance to win $250 please..."/>
<meta name="keywords" content="Forum, Thread, Post, Win, Welcome, Twitter"/>
```

.

So, how? I'm so confused having spent an hour goolging this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the laravel docs about Template Inheritance (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#template-inheritance)

You can than inject the meta data into your `<head></head>` by using `@section('title',$article->title)` in your blade

Example of your situation:

```
<head>
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="@yield('twitter_title')">
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="@yield('twitter_image')">
</head>
```

In your blade:

```
@extends('layouts.layout') //This loads the default blade with your <head></head> section

@section('twitter_title',$article->title)
@section('twitter_image',$article->image)
```

Comment: So I added the code like shown above. First box (head and meta stuff) I chucked in my layout.blade.php file. The second bit, I chucked into home.blade.php file. It didn't seem to work through. Doesn't seem to be appending the data from @section in my home.blade.php into my layout.blade.php.

Comment: Can you provide your code you created? Do you get any errors?
Edit: I guess you have loaded your layout.blade.php into your home.blade.php with this line: `@extends('layouts.layout')` (where layouts is your folder that contains the `layout.blade.php`

Comment: I missed that step. Sort of working now, but now, It's asking me for different variables in the layout.blade.php file e.g. $ip $port $default_css to be defined in the home.blade.php file, surely there's a way for it to continue to read the other file for that?

Comment: Hm okay, and these 'missing' variables are defined in your home.blade.php? You should read this documentation about blades https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade So you can see if you are using the laravel components and @sections in the right order

Comment: So the missing variables are not defined in my home.blade.php, they are variables that extend past the <head></head> tags. They are part of the layout.blade.php content in the <body> tags.